# Remove everything after hyphen in hyphenated names in Excel using Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am in charge of adding new employees to our speech recognition and gamification systems.

When I get a batch of tickets, I compile a bunch of data into a spreadsheet that I then reference when adding those users to the systems (Which unfortunately do not have a JSON/CSV upload option or anything similar)

To save some time with compiling, I've started exporting a bunch of data from our database and our HR management system into that sheet, and then using the new employee's email to XLOOKUP all the other data fields.

For one of our systems, it has a strict character limit, and the format for the username is "cde\firstname.lastname". This is no problem to CONCATENATE normally, but it has a strict character limit, so if the user has a hyphenated last name, I will basically dump everything after the hyphen.

At first I tried a simple formula using a combination of LEFT and FIND -1 to find the hyphen, and then take everything to the left of it. This obviously doesn't end up working because I get a #VALUE! for anyone without a hyphen in their last name.

I tried using IFERROR to say "OK try to return the last name without a hyphen, otherwise just return the last name", but for some reason when I put the reference in the Return_If_Error portion, it doesn't recognize it as a reference.

So I am looking for a formula that will work with a LOOKUP'd value and only give me what's before a hyphen, but otherwise will still just give me the last name.

The baseline formula I have, that just looks up and concatenates the first and last into the "cde\firstname.lastname" is:

```
=CONCATENATE("cde\",LOWER(XLOOKUP(G578,Sheet4!M:M,Sheet4!B:B)),".",LOWER(XLOOKUP(G578,Sheet4!M:M,Sheet4!C:C)))
```

Comment: So use an if() to do a logical test for a hyphen and do one expression for if a hyphen is present and another if it is not.

Comment: `put the reference in the Return_If_Error portion..` how does the reference look like?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comments, you've got the right idea, just use an `IF` statement for testing if the string contains "-", then use the normal string functions like `FIND`, `LEFT`, etc. to pick out the things you want.

For example:

```
="cde/"&
LEFT(H1,FIND(".",H1)-1)&
IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",H1)),MID(H1,FIND(".",H1),FIND("-",H1)-FIND(".",H1)),
MID(H1,FIND(".",H1),FIND("@",H1)-FIND(".",H1)))
```

[image]